# Unidrected graph representation in qucik graph

Tags: c#, c++, boost, boost-graph, quickgraph

I am using [QuickGraph .NET library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5603/QuickGraph-A-C-graph-library-with-Graphviz-Sup) which is a clone for boost (C++) graph library but I have some few questions as I'm totally new to this library 
1- How would I represent undirected graph in QucikGraph? I found that you can do it easily in boost using: 
 `adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS> Graph;`

2- How would I assign values to vertices I am interested to attach integer values to vertices but I couldn't figure out how to do this:

```
AdjacencyGraph graph = new AdjacencyGraph(new VertexAndEdgeProvider(), false);//I'm not sure about the proper value of this boolean 
IVertex u = graph.AddVertex();// here I'm adding vertex to 'graph' but with no value 
IVertex v = graph.AddVertex();// here also I'm doing the same thing but without assigning any value to vertex v
graph.AddEdge(u, v);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to go about it: Suppose your vertices `vertex1` and `vertex2` are of type `T`, you should use the following piece of code (NB: Namespace will be `using QuickGraph;`):

```
AdjacencyGraph<T, Edge<T>> newGraphInstance = new AdjacencyGraph<int, Edge<int>>();
newGraphInstance.AddVerticesAndEdge(new Edge<T>(vertex1, vertex2));
```

This will add both the vertices and the corresponding edge.